# Method chaining without final method

Tags: php, oop

I came across plenty of examples of method chaining in PHP, but couldn't find anything about this one, so I'm asking for help you guys;)

My problem is - can I in some way find out if the method in chain is the last one? In most cases people are using some sort of final method (execute, send,..) to tell when the chain ends and return the corresponding result. But I wonder if there is some hidden magic method or technique than can check all the methods in chain and detect if there is no next method?
Without final method it works fine for strings (in the very simple example), but not if I want to return array.

Here is my snippet :

```php
class Chain {
    private $strArray;

    function __call($name, $args) {
        $this->strArray[] = $args[0];
        return $this;
    }
    function __toString() {
        return implode('-', $this->strArray);
    }
}
// example 1
$c = new Chain();
$x = $c->foo('hi')->bar('stack'); // need array('hi', 'stack')

// example 2
$c = new Chain();
$x = $c->foo('hi')->bar('stack')->foobar('overflow'); // need array('hi', 'stack', 'overflow')

// example 3
$c = new Chain();
echo $c->foo('hi')->foobar('overflow'); // prints 'hi-overflow'

// example 4
$c = new Chain();
echo $c->foo('hi')->bar('stack')->foobar('overflow'); // prints 'hi-stack-overflow'
```

You see, when I want to print the result of chain, I can modify the result in the `__toString` method, but what if I need an array (example 1, 2)? Is there any way to achieve that without calling some additional "final" method?

Thanks a lot for help and let me know if you need more info.

**EDIT:** After feedback from @bandi I tried to extend `ArrayObject` like this.

```
class Chain extends ArrayObject {
    function __call($name, $args) {
        $this->append($args[0]);
        return $this;
    }
    function __toString() {
        return implode('-', $this->getIterator()->getArrayCopy());
    }
}
// returned ref. to object, works fine in loop or accessing offset
$obj = new Chain;
$x = $obj->foo('hi')->bar('stack')->foobar('overflow'); // need array('hi', 'stack', 'overflow')
foreach ($x as $y) {
    echo $y, "\n";
}
var_dump($x[0], $x[1], $x[2]);

// returned String
$c = new Chain;
echo $c->foo('hi')->foobar('overflow'); // prints 'hi-overflow'
```

It does what I wanted, however I don't feel so good about the `$this->getIterator()->getArrayCopy()` part. Is there some simple way of accessing the array (internally in `["storage":"ArrayObject":private]`)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method chaining is using the return value of a function, in this case this is the reference to the object. Predicting the use of a returned value is generally not possible.

You have to tell the called method that you want to do something different. You can use the second argument for this, e.g. you return a different result if the second argument is defined. The other option might be to modify the class so that it behaves like an array except if it is printed.

Comment: ok, thanks. Generally I would like to return array when assigning to variable, but still have the open option to cast to string. As I return $this I don't get the class property ($strArray) but the whole reference to class, which is not desired and it forces me to implement the "final" method. But maybe really easiest will be to pass second argument TRUE to the last method in chain, as you suggested. I will see if there will come more advices;)

Comment: btw. how did you mean - "The other option might be to modify the class so that it behaves like an array except if it is printed."?? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: @lp1051 I am not completely familiar with php's class system in the newer versions, so I don't know if it's possible or not: I meant that you derive your class from the 'array' class and then add your two custom methods.